# How to refresh GRAL chart after changing data?

Tags: java, charts

I have a GRAL chart connected to a datasource:

```
XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(data);
chartPanel=new InteractivePanel(plot);
LineRenderer lines = new DefaultLineRenderer2D();
plot.setLineRenderer(data, lines);
Color c1 = new Color(0.0f, 0.3f, 1.0f); 
plot.getLineRenderer(zl).setSetting(LineRenderer.COLOR, c2);
```

Variable 'data' changes through time and this piece of code is executed after changes. How can I make the graph refresh with new data? I tried repaint(), revalidate() but no effect...

Answer (score 0):

After updating `data` call `chartPanel.repaint()`. If it would did not work make you sure that you are changing the right `data` and updating the right `chartPanel.repaint()`, as Rick already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need this any more, but this is how I do it:

```
import de.erichseifert.gral.ui.InteractivePanel;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PlotFunctions {

    public void AddChartToPanel(InteractivePanel chart, JPanel jPanelChart) {
        // erase panel
        Graphics g = jPanelChart.getGraphics();
        g.dispose();

        jPanelChart.paintComponents(g);
        jPanelChart.removeAll();

        // paint new chart
        chart.setSize(jPanelChart.getWidth(), jPanelChart.getHeight());
        chart.setVisible(true);
        jPanelChart.add(chart);
        jPanelChart.validate();
        jPanelChart.repaint();
    }


    public void Resize(JPanel jPanelChart){
        if (jPanelChart.getComponentCount() > 0) {
            Component c = jPanelChart.getComponent(0);
            c.setSize(jPanelChart.getWidth(), jPanelChart.getHeight());
            jPanelChart.removeAll();
            jPanelChart.add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the Resize function on the panel you use to plot, basically refresh the picture by deleting it from the Panel and re plotting it with new dimensions, it might help in your case.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, plots in GRAL are register themselves as `DataListener`, so the displayed plot should automatically refresh when values are added, changed, or removed to the `DataSource` objects. Maybe you've hit a bug or there's something wrong with the code that changes your data.